# Objective-C library for accessing SVN

Tags: objective-c, svn, macos

Are there any Objective-C libraries available for accessing SVN repositories. It is a very difficult thing to Google for due to the high correlation on the words involved. I would like to use one in an OSX 10.6 application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use Subversion set of [C libraries](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.developer.usingapi.html). You can use them in a Cocoa/Objective-C application with no modifications at all.